# How to find RHOST/RPORT ? | Python 3.9

Tags: python, ip, malware

I'm working out on a backdoor script on Python and I tested it on my computer and it worked fine, but when I asked a friend to test it on his computer it didn't work well.

I have 2 python files, 1 for the server which I use to wait the connection of the user and the other one which is the backdoor which is where the user opens it.
Now on these both script I have for the server LHOST/LPORT and for the usr RHOST/RPORT

I know that on the server I need to put a port and my ip address but I don't know what to put on the user file.

Here is a photo of both scripts:

[image: In the right part of the script there is the backdoor script where is the usr and on the left there is the server.]

The problem is that I don't know what the RHOST will be. Do I need the user ip?

Answer (score 0):

RHOST is user public ip (open browser and digit whats my ip) , if it's a remote host (not same network).
Instead if it's a local host (in the same network), the local ip ("ip a s" for linux "ipconfig" for windows).
But maybe the problem is in the need to open ports, (port forwarding)